# How to start gvim from command line with predefine pasting from clipboard

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, os-clipboard

I know `gvim -c [command] samaple.txt` might run command predefined in command body. How to paste text from windows clipboard at the end of sample.txt file?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know [the clipboard cannot be accessed from the command line natively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819814/how-can-you-get-the-clipboard-contents-with-a-windows-command). So that's going to be the biggest problem here. If you put the data somewhere accessible like a text file you could certainly use `[command]` to do the rest. Something like:

```
gvim +"let @\"= {someData}" +"normal! Gp" sample.txt
```

But, as Peter Rincker mentioned if vim is complied with the `+clipboard` option this is actually quite possible:

```
gvim +"$put+" sample.txt
```

`+` is a special register that points to the clipboard. `$put+` "puts" the `+` register at the end of the file.

Comment: If (g)Vim is compiled properly with `+clipboard` then the `"+` register can be used. e.g. `gvim -c '$put+` sample.txt`

Comment: @PeterRincker That is a very good point. Hmm... I feel bad stealing your answer though.

Comment: You have my blessing, please post it as your own

Comment: Powershell can do it, something like this: `Powershell -command Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetText()`

Comment: command `normal! G"+p` works fine under linux, but somehow under windows it paste at the last line after first character. What is going on?

Comment: @lluke Not sure, it works on my Windows 7 machine.

Comment: On Windows with default Vim configuration clipboard is stored in `*` register, not `+`.

Comment: ...of course, not everyone uses default configuration. There are many ways to change the behavior of gVim w/r/t copy/paste, clipboard and registers. See help for `guioptions`, `clipboard-autoselect`, `gui-selections` for starters.

Comment: (Actually on Windows I believe * and + are the same thing but Vim docs refer to clipboard in quote-star register so it's good to follow convention. My second comment is still relevant for those having issues.)

Comment: @lluke You must have text on the very last line of the file in which case this is working as designed. Try the same thing manually. When you hit `G` you go to first column of last line. If you had a blank line at the end of the file it would look better. You could do `+"norm! Go" +"norm! \"*p"`.

Comment: @BLayer Actually apparently it depends on what's in the clipboard. If it's a full line vim pastes it in linewise, otherwise it uses characterwise. I'll update to make it independent.

Comment: Right, I assumed they selected a line fragment. But good to spell it out as you suggest. Alternatively one can use `:put` which is always linewise. ... @lluke try this instead  `+"$put *"`

Answer (score 1):

`"+` is a special register. It refers to system clipboard.

You can paste the content of windows clipboard into current cursor position by using the below command:

```
"+p
```